# Libgdx, how can I create a rectangle from coordinates?

Tags: java, libgdx, rectangles

I am currently trying to make a selector box for an RTS game. For this I need to be able to drag the mouse in order to create the selection box, however this can lead to a negative length/width.

In Libgdx is there a way to make rectangle from just using 2 sets of coordinates?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*this is a simple idea, if I understand what you want to do:*

to create a rectangle you can use this, `Rectangle(float x, float y, float width, float height)` for more inforamacion you can read it here http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Rectangle.html

*this a psuedo code more or less:*

create a listener that captures keystrokes, mouse or them as appropriate,

in touchdown catches x, y, and assign a:

```
yourVariableTouchDown.x = x;
yourVariableTouchDown.y = y;
```

then when the touchup captures the x is executed, and the point where it makes up touch and assign a:

```
yourVariableTouchUp.x = x;
yourVariableTouchUp.y = y;
```

after create the rectagle:

```
private Rectangle yourRectangle = new Rectangle();

yourRectangle(yourVariableTouchDown.x, yourVariableTouchDown.y,
              (yourVariableTouchDown.x - yourVariableTouchUp.x), 
              (yourVariableTouchDown.y - yourVariableTouchUp.y));
```

if you want to see it you can use `ShapeRenderer:`
look this http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html

**add for test in variable class**

```
private ShapeRenderer sRDebugRectangel = new ShapeRenderer();
```

**add for test in update or draw**

```
sRDebugRectangel.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
sRDebugRectangel.identity();

sRDebugRectangel.rect(yourRectangle.getX(), 
                      yourRectangle.getY(),
                      yourRectangle.getWidth(),
                      yourRectangle.getHeight());

sRDebugRectangel.end();
```

you can look on that listener use:
https://www.google.es/#q=listener+libgdx

P.S: what you say negative, will be a matter of check when touchup is less than touchdown change where the rectangle is created that was just what I happened to you have test it and adjust the variables to create the rectangle now because you can not be created desirably when negative, now I have time to get with it, in fact eh not tested this why I said it was pseudo code, hope you serve, idea

P.S: You can also look at this https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Thanks, that looks great - going to try and add it now!