# How can I rotate Rectangles in Libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I rotated my sprite 90 degrees and I want to do the same with my rectangle to be able to use them for collision, but the `rotate()` method is not available on rectangles.

This is what I did:

```
treeSpr=new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("tree.png")));
        treeSpr.setPosition(250,700);
        treeSpr.rotate(90f); 

//Rectangle
 treeRect=new Rectangle(treeSpr.getX(),treeSpr.getHeight(),
                treeSpr.getWidth(),treeSpr.getHeight());
```

Comment: Have you tried using Box2D?

Comment: Hello you can implement an own Rect class or ... I don't know how exactly you did the rotation. But you can make use of rotation and translation matrices so collision can be processed as if your sprite is still at 0 degree and use normal rect

Comment: No I haven't tried Box2d yet, Can you give me an example of the code? sorry I'm new to java and game development

Comment: What do you want to do with the rectangle? Another suggestion is to use an Actor of type Image that can easily be rotated and scaled.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The other answer is basically correct; however, I had some issues with the positioning of the polygons using that method.  Just some clarification:

**LibGDX does not support rotated Rectangles when using the Intersector for collision dectection.**  If you need rotated rectangles, you should use the [Polygon](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Polygon.html) for collision detection instead.

## Building a Rectangular Polygon:

```
polygon = new Polygon(new float[]{0,0,bounds.width,0,bounds.width,bounds.height,0,bounds.height});
```

Don't forget to set the origin of the Polygon if you are going to rotate it:

```
polygon.setOrigin(bounds.width/2, bounds.height/2);
```

Now you can rotate the collision polygon:

```
polygon.setRotation(degrees);
```

Also, somewhere in your code, you will likely want to update the position of the collision polygon to match your sprite:

```
polygon.setPosition(x, y);
```

We can even draw our polygon on screen (for debug purposes):

```
drawDebug(ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer) {
    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
    shapeRenderer.polygon(polygon.getTransformedVertices());
    shapeRenderer.end();
}
```

## Collision Detection:

The overlapConvexPolygons() of the [Intersector](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Intersector.html):

```
boolean collision = Intersector.overlapConvexPolygons(polygon1, polygon2)
```

As mentioned in the other answer, this method only works if:

- using convex polygons, which the rectangle is
- performing polygon to polygon checks, e.g.: you cannot mix rectangles and
  polygons

Comment: Instead of calling `setPosition(x, y)` separately, why not create the Polygon correctly at the position of the Rectangle? See the [https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Polygon.html#Polygon-float:A-](docs) for the `float[] vertices` parameter of the constructor.

Comment: Also keep in mind, the `Polygon.setRotation(degrees)` method will not do the same as the `Sprite.rotate(degrees)` method. The former will set the rotation regardless of the current rotation, while the latter will increase the rotation by the specified degrees.

Answer (score 6):

## Rotation

You could create a [Polygon](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Polygon.html) from the rectangle or from the sprite (supplying the vertices in order for the polygon constructor) and use it's `rotate(float degrees)` method:

```
treePoly = new Polygon(new float[] {
               treeRect.x, treeRect.y,
               treeRect.x, treeRect.y + treeRect.height,
               treeRect.x + treeRect.width, treeRect.y + treeRect.height,
               treeRect.x + treeRect.width, treeRect.y
           });

treePoly.rotate(45f);
```

## Collision Detection

Collision checks then could be done via the [Intersector](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Intersector.html) class:

```
Intersector.overlapConvexPolygons(polygon1, polygon2)
```

Keep in mind though, this method only works if:

- you use [convex polygons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polygon), which the rectangle is
- you do polygon to polygon checks, e.g.: you cannot mix rectangles and polygons

Answer (score 1):

I think something like it can help, I can not test now,

```
//Rectangle
 treeRect=new Rectangle(treeSpr.getX(),
                        treeSpr.getY(),
                        treeSpr.getHeight(), //now is change width by height
                        treeSpr.getWidth());  //now is change height by width
```

Note: may You need to adjust the origin of the rotation for both

you can use a render ShapeRenderer to see if the result is as expected:

***add*** for test in variable class

```
private ShapeRenderer sRDebugRectangel = new ShapeRenderer();
```

***add*** for test in update or draw

```
sRDebugRectangel.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
sRDebugRectangel.identity();

sRDebugRectangel.rect(yourRectangle.getX(), 
                      yourRectangle.getY(),
                      yourRectangle.getWidth(),
                      yourRectangle.getHeight());

sRDebugRectangel.end();
```

can look at my answer to this question to use a shaperrender otherwise known as:

[Libgdx, how can I create a rectangle from coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125125/libgdx-how-can-i-create-a-rectangle-from-coordinates/28125845#28125845)