# how to visualize a rectangle

Tags: java, libgdx, rectangles

I have two rectangles in Libgdx but they seem not to overlap right. Is there a way so I see where the rectangles are?

I have this:

```
Body2.setSize(72, 72);
Body2.setPosition(20, squiddyY);
Body.setHeight(Assets.sprite_body.getHeight());
Body.setPosition(pipe1X, Assets.sprite_body.getY()+Assets.sprite_body.getHeight());
if(Body2.overlaps(Body)){
    squiddyY=1000;
}
```

but it looks like body is half size of sprite_body(or the Y is just too low?) and is a bit behind it (the X location of sprite_body is pipe1X). Maybe i'm putting it at the wrong place so visualizing it will really help.

Comment: Eh, you draw one? Afterwards? On top?

Comment: you can watch part of my answer, here, I think he can help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30554629/how-can-i-rotate-rectangles-in-libgdx/30556098#30556098

Answer (score 0):

You can draw shapes with ShapeRenderer
http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html

The link includes examples.

Comment: I actually saw that page earlier. I didn't understand though how to use it on the rectangle